# Problema con una Funcion PHP buscar links

Tags: php

Tengo un Problema con esta funciona lo que quiero hacer es lo siguénte quiero que busque los datos del link pero que no me de un informacion de error junto con la correta y si no hay datos me de un mensaje de error

```
    function External_links($Link_info){


        $content = '
            "url_line":"/youtube.com(.+)v=([^&]+)/";
            "url_line":"/vimeo.com\/([a-z1-9.-_]+)/";
            "url_line":"/facebook.com\/[a-z1-9.-_]+/";
        ';

        if (preg_match_all('#"url_line":[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $content, $resultado)) {
            $mp = $resultado[1];   
        } else {
            $mp = ['sin coincidencias']; // este mensaje de error
        }

        foreach ($mp as $nombre) {
            if(isset($Link_info)) :
            $url = $Link_info;



                if(preg_match($nombre, $url)) {
            //=== youtube information generator 
                    echo 'yes <br>';
                }else{
                    //-- Error 404
                    echo 'no funciona <br>';
                } 

            endif;///
        }
    }

echo External_links('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OawLX0jVRVU');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una variable que contenga el resultado y que cambie si encuentra el url.  Algo asi:

```
<?php
function External_links($Link_info){

        $content = '
            "url_line":"/youtube.com(.+)v=([^&]+)/";
            "url_line":"/vimeo.com\/([a-z1-9.-_]+)/";
            "url_line":"/facebook.com\/[a-z1-9.-_]+/";
        ';

        if (preg_match_all('#"url_line":[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $content, $resultado)) {
            $mp = $resultado[1];   
        } else {
            $mp = ['sin coincidencias']; // este mensaje de error
        }
        $result = 'no funciona <br>';
        foreach ($mp as $nombre) {
            if(isset($Link_info)) :
                $url = $Link_info;    

                if(preg_match($nombre, $url)) {                
                    $result = 'yes <br>';
                }

            endif;///
        }
        return $result;
    }

echo External_links('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OawLX0jVRVU');

?>
```